# Inheritate relation from MappedSuperclass

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I created a MappedSuperclass named "CommonClass" which contains some commons attributes of a large number of other classes. In addition, I need that class specifies common relations, for example with another class named "RelationClass".

I proceed like that :

```
/* ##### CommonClass ##### */
@MappedSuperclass
public class CommonClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_relation_class")
    private RelationClass relationClass;

    // === Class getters & setters ===============================
    ... 
}
/* ##### CommonClass ##### */


/* ##### ChildClass ##### */
@Entity
public class ChildClass extends CommonClass{

    private String specificAttribute;
    ...

    // === Class getters & setters ===============================
    ...
}
/* ##### ChildClass ##### */


/* ##### RelationClass ##### */
@Entity
public class RelationClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "relationClass")
    private List<CommonClass> commonList = new ArrayList<CommonClass>();

    // === Class getters & setters ===============================
    ...
}
/* ##### RelationClass ##### */
```

The problem is that dosen't recognize CommonClass as an entity, which is right but it's a MappedSuperClass so logically it should make child classes inheritate the relation.

This is the error I get :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.xxx.dao.entities.RelationClass.objectList[com.xxx.dao.entities.CommonClass]
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.xxx.dao.entities.RelationClass.objectList[com.xxx.dao.entities.CommonClass]
```

Comment: I guess instead of `List<CommonClass>` you should write `List<ChildClass>`

Comment: If I do that, it's like that I put the relation on the ChildClass directly. Actually I have 8 Classes as Child, so ... it will be easier to put the relation on each of them then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems to be impossible. As mentionned on the link bellow :
"The main disadvantage of mapped superclasses is that they cannot be queried or persisted. **You also cannot have a relationship to a mapped superclass**..."

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance

Answer (score 0):

> but it's a MappedSuperClass so logically it should make child classes inheritate the relation.

I think the reason is that Hibernate (or whatever is the JPA implementation) cannot be sure at the stage of startup that the class you will be adding to the `@OneToMany` list will **surely** be an entity. One can even add a Java class that extends from `CommonClass` but is not an `@Entity`.

Comment: It's logic, effectevely we can extend a non entity class from CommonClass ... did you know how I can do to mix inheritance and relations ?